# Custom Assert using Chai (node js)

Tags: node.js, automation, assert, chai

I am working on an XML validate /parser script using Chai (node.js) and asserting xml against set of values stored in excel sheet.

I am iterating code/function (validate(dataPath, dataValue)) over rows present in excel sheet. Now the **problem is if assert fail, instead of going to next row, assert terminates the entire code.
is it possible to customize the assert to perform some task (like  if fail (print some msg; continue ;) or is there any other way to solve this problem.**

```
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
   workbook.xlsx.readFile('utils/valid.xlsx')
                        .then(function() {
                            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
                            worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
                                //count++;
                                console.log(rowNumber);
                                var row = worksheet.getRow(rowNumber);
                                var dataPath1 =  row.getCell("A").value;
                                var dataPath2 =  row.getCell("B").value;
                                var dataPath = '/PlaceFulfillmentOrderRequest'+dataPath1+dataPath2;
                                console.log(dataPath);
                                var dataValue = row.getCell("D").value
                                console.log(dataValue);
                                validate (dataPath,dataValue);

                            });

})

 function validate(dataPath, dataValue){
       fs.readFile('utils/PlaceFulfillmentOrder.xml', 'utf8', function (err,data) { 
          if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ");
            return console.log(err);
          }
          var doc = new dom().parseFromString(data);
          var subId = xpath.select1(dataPath, doc);
          var value = subId.lastChild.data;
          console.log("actual value: " + value);
          assert.equal(value, dataValue, 'Not matched') 
          console.log("passed")
      });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a try / catch? Might not be the most elegant solution but I think it will work. Something like try {assert.equal(value, dataValue, 'Not matched') } catch {console.log("the assertion failed");}

Comment: @edencorbin .. try catch did solved my problem bc chai/assertion library was handling the exception. So i modified assertion.js file to perform according to required behavior